# Shorter way for tuple elements retargeting in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

Currently, I use something like this in one of my functions: (all variables are used with more complex functions, but for what I will be asking it doesn't matter and I simplify)

```
fun RecursiveCall (p, q, r, s) =
  let
    val (ra, rb, rc) = returnResult (p, q, s)
  in
    RecursiveCall (p, ra, rb, rc)
  end
```

How can I write this in a shorter and (perhaps) nicer way? Meaning, how can I extract the elements of a tuple that was returned from a function and pass these as arguments of another tuple?

Note: One could also write simply `RecursiveCall (p, #1 (returnResult (p, q, s)) , #2 (returnResult (p, q, s)), #3 (returnResult (p, q, s)))` but (probably) this would in some circumstances cause the same thing to run three times, i.e. returnResult.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to say anything general without knowledge about your actual problem, but you could group the last three elements of the tuple together (it looks like they are a unit), like

```
fun RecursiveCall p (q, r, s) = RecursiveCall p (returnResult (p, q, s))
```

Comment: No, they are not in general. I am not asking for any specific problem, only if a general proposal exists in SML/NJ.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> (p, #1 (returnResult (p, q, s)),
>     #2 (returnResult (p, q, s)),
>     #3 (returnResult (p, q, s)))
> ```
>
> this would *[...]* cause the same thing to run three times

Yes, that's right. And it's also more verbose than your original proposal.

You could also write e.g.

```
case returnResult (p, q, s) of
  (ra, rb, rc) => recursiveCall (p, ra, rb, rc)
```

as an alternative to let-in-end.

You could make `returnResult` and `recursiveCall` [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) functions and use `uncurry3`:

```
fun curry3 f x y z = f (x, y, z)
fun uncurry3 f (x, y, z) = f x y z

fun returnResult p q s = (p + 1, q + 2, s + 3)
fun recursiveCall p q r s =
  uncurry3 (recursiveCall p) (returnResult p q s)
```

Here, `recursiveCall p` is partially applied to one of its four arguments, making it a function that accepts three curried arguments. `uncurry3 (recursiveCall p)` thus becomes a function that accepts a 3-tuple, which is the precise result of `returnResult p q s`.

This method relies on the order of arguments conveniently fitting together.

But I think this is a symptom of `returnResult` returning too many things.

Ideally functions return the one thing their name suggests that it computes.

Perhaps some of the computations that `returnResult` does can be split into multiple functions, or perhaps they're really one thing and should be wrapped in a common data type, or perhaps `p`, `q` and `s` are better passed as implicit arguments of a reader/state monad. I don't have a good example of how the last thing looks in ML at hand, but I also can't say what the situation warrants, since the code is hypothetical.

Comment: Well, since some pre-computed structures do exist and are in the ra, rb, rc data structures, I was thinking of taking advantage of them again, not re-computing, since they actually could find a use further down in another function.